# Fixing Duplicate Columns SQL

Tags: sql, duplicates, snowflake-schema

I have the following code:

```
update tble
set 
offer_id_02 = offer_id_03,
offer_id_03 = offer_id_04,
offer_id_04 = offer_id_05,
offer_id_05 = offer_id_06,
offer_id_06 = offer_id_07,
offer_id_07 = offer_id_08,
offer_id_08 = NULL
where offer_id_02 = offer_id_01;


update tble
set 
offer_id_03 = offer_id_04,
offer_id_04 = offer_id_05,
offer_id_05 = offer_id_06,
offer_id_06 = offer_id_07,
offer_id_07 = offer_id_08,
offer_id_08 = NULL
where offer_id_03 = offer_id_01 or offer_id_03 = offer_id_02; 


update tble
set 
offer_id_04 = offer_id_05,
offer_id_05 = offer_id_06,
offer_id_06 = offer_id_07,
offer_id_07 = offer_id_08,
offer_id_08 = NULL
where offer_id_04 = offer_id_01 or offer_id_04 = offer_id_02 or offer_id_04 = offer_id_03;


update tble
set 
offer_id_05 = offer_id_06,
offer_id_06 = offer_id_07,
offer_id_07 = offer_id_08,
offer_id_08 = NULL
where offer_id_05 = offer_id_01 or offer_id_05 = offer_id_02 or offer_id_05 = offer_id_03 or offer_id_05 = offer_id_04;


update tble
set 
offer_id_06 = offer_id_07,
offer_id_07 = offer_id_08,
offer_id_08 = NULL
where offer_id_06 = offer_id_01 or offer_id_06 = offer_id_02 or offer_id_06 = offer_id_03 or offer_id_06 = offer_id_04 or offer_id_06 = offer_id_05;


update tble
set 
offer_id_07 = offer_id_08,
offer_id_08 = NULL
where offer_id_07 = offer_id_01 or offer_id_07 = offer_id_02 or offer_id_07 = offer_id_03 or offer_id_07 = offer_id_04 or offer_id_07 = offer_id_05  or offer_id_07 = offer_id_06;


update tble
set 
offer_id_08 = NULL
where offer_id_08 = offer_id_01 or offer_id_08 = offer_id_02 or offer_id_08 = offer_id_03 or offer_id_08 = offer_id_04 or offer_id_08 = offer_id_05 or offer_id_08 = offer_id_06 or offer_id_08 = offer_id_07;
```

Essentially, I have a SQL table with a customer and 8 offers they get as a promotion. Due to bad logic, some duplicates come through. To fix this I "scoot over" the duplicate offer and null out offer_id_08 slot. The issue is, the logic is different depending on which offers are duplicate to each other. How can I build this out in a concise way?

Comment: A table that was just `customer | offer | id (or rank)` would be so much easier to maintain and it could grow to accommodate any number of offers beyond 8. Is that an option, or is this table design stuck the way it is?

Comment: I cannot change this table, but this is a good point that I can maybe reformat this table and then run the updates. Maybe via CTE or temp table (?)

Comment: Busy day today. That's what I was thinking. I'm not sure how feasible it is, but unpivot, dedup, rerank (`ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY customer ORDER BY offer_id`), pivot, and update.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, as a first step, you could try to merge your queries into one big query, using CASE's and combined WHERE's:

```
UPDATE table
SET offer_id_02 = 
   CASE 
      WHEN offer_id_02 = offer_id_01 THEN offer_id_03
      ELSE offer_id_02
   END,
   offer_id_03 = 
   CASE 
      WHEN offer_id_03 = offer_id_01 OR offer_id_03 = offer_id_02 THEN offer_id_04
      ELSE offer_id_03
   END,
  ...
  offer_id_08 = NULL
WHERE 
     offer_id_01 IN (offer_id_02, offer_id_03, offer_id_04, offer_id_05, offer_id_06, offer_id_07, offer_id_08)
  OR offer_id_02 IN (offer_id_03, offer_id_04, offer_id_05, offer_id_06, offer_id_07, offer_id_08)
  ...
  OR offer_id_07 = offer_id_08;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a trivial way to reformat (un-pivot, flatten) your table as @JNevill suggests, 4 repeating attributes per record for an illustration.

```sql
create table the_table (
 id serial, 
 attr_1 integer, 
 attr_2 integer,
 attr_3 integer,
 attr_4 integer
);

insert into the_table (attr_1,attr_2,attr_3,attr_4) 
values 
 (10, 11, 12, 13),
 (20, 21, 22, 23),
 (30, 31, 32, 33);

select t.id, l.*
from the_table t
cross join lateral (
 select 'attr_1', attr_1 union all
 select 'attr_2', attr_2 union all
 select 'attr_3', attr_3 union all
 select 'attr_4', attr_4
) as l(attr_name, attr_value);
```

You can shape the abobe as a CTE and then select `distinct on (id, attr_value)`.

[DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/p5NCjPXaGSGodDJSgGvRT9/0)

**Edit**
The above is a PostgreSQL example. Under MSSQL, SnowFlake and Spark that support native `UNPIVOT` clause, it is simpler.